# Apple In App Purchase for Java(FX)

Tags: java, macos, javafx, in-app-purchase

I'm looking at building an app in for deployment on the Mac OS X platform.  I've recently cut my teeth on JavaFX and find it to be fun and useful.  I am aware of various projects that allow you to port a JavaFX application to both [iOS](https://blogs.oracle.com/jfxprg/entry/ipack_the_ios_application_packager) and as an [App in the Appstore](http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/).  What I am wondering is, is there a project that has wrapped Apple's Store APIs (StoreKit.framework?) in Java to allow for in app purchases?